# how to overwrite `display: none` for checkbox?

Tags: css, css-selectors, display, inline-styles

Currently at this web page there is a [table](http://zz.zustatzdravy.cz/kalkulator/)

It looks like the default template of the web got in CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Now the checkboxes are not visible -  see [image]

But if I uncheck the `display: none` then the checkboxes are visible.

Is there any way I can make them visible in html using `style` when creating the checkbox? I do not have the permission to edit css. I can add custom css though.

Comment: `display: block !important;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely these should be inline-blocks when visible (i.e. not taking the whole width of their parent), so you can add the attribute `style="display: inline-block"` to those HTML tags.

Comment: it looks like this answer is the neatest one... Any suggestion how to move the checkbox to the very right? And keep the same vertical alignment? Meaning to keep it horizontaly centered?

Comment: If you are sure that both always fit into one line, you could use `text-align: justify-all` on those `td`s. A safer, but more complicated way would be to nest a `div` into that `td`, wrap a `span` around the text (or a `label` tag) and apply `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to that `div`. (You can't apply `display:  flex` directly to the `td`, since that would make it loose its cell function)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes**, you can add an inline css in order to show the checkbox.

Just add one of the following `style="display: inline-block;"` or `style="display: block;"` based on your needs.

This because of [css priority](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp), the inline css has the most priority.

**Demo**

```css
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{display: none;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td> Balance
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: inline-block;">
  </td>
  <td>Element 2 </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It works nicely. Thank you. Could you help me to place the check box horizontaly align in the middle? It is currently a the top. `"display: inherit; vertical-align: middle;"` does not work

Comment: @Radek don't use inherit but use inline-block

Comment: Why not inherit? Inline block places the checkbox in the upper left corner. I want it to be right and horizontally in the middle.

Comment: @Radek put the content of the `td` inside a `div`, and put the text inside a `span` (so something like `<td><div><span>...</span><input...></div></td>`), then remove padding and margin from both `span` and `input` and to the `div` apply `display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items:center`

Comment: @Dwhitz the other answer was working little bit better for me so I accepted it.